# Not see all value of loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, jenkins

I'm display some elements with JSON

I have to post the next job on each iteration knowing that the first one is toto

So for now I have: toto titi

And I can not see how to loop to see all the rest. Can you explain what can I do ?

```
global.globalgroupname = "toto"; // start
let prevgroupname;

// Assume the chain ends when groupname is null or blank
while (globalgroupname) {
    // Do something with groupname
    // ...
    // reset globalgroupname to exit if ajax call fails
    prevgroupname = globalgroupname;
    globalgroupname = null;
    // Get next globalgroupname
    getall(prevgroupname); 
}

function getall(groupname) {
    console.log(groupname);
    //toto
    ajaxGet(".../" + groupname + "/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}

function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
    ...
}

function recover(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    
            console.log(group.name);    
            //titi
            // Save in global state
            globalgroupname = group.name;
        });          
}
```

DownStreamProject show the next job for example in my case :

- toto shows titi

and know i need to do a loop for each job and have next job like this:

- titi shows exm1
- exm1 shows exm2
- and continue ...

Thanks for yout help

Comment: `while (globalgroupname)` has `globalgroupname = null;` inside of it, which means the next time it loops the condition will be false and the loop would be terminated. `getAll` appears to be asynchronous, so it would run *after* that code, so it will never set `globalgroupname` in time for the loop to check it when it's filled.

Comment: Ok, what do you advise me to do ...